# Need to get an integer value using an SQL statement in Access

Tags: ms-access

Keep getting expected expression error with this code.

Qty = Select tblTransActions.[Quanity]From tbltransActions;

Would like to get the the interger value from this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use *DLookup* for such tasks:

```
Qty = DLookup("[Quantity]", "[tbltransActions]")
```

But you may need to filter that ...

Comment: Ok thank you. I do use dlookup and get stack overflow.   
 
 Do While Not rs.EOF
        Qty = Nz(DLookup("[Quanity]", "tblTransActions", "[Tool_ID] = '" & Forms!frmMultiCkO!Tyonek_ID & "' AND [Patron_ID] = '" & Forms!frmMultiCkO!txtPatrons & "'"), 0)
        Total = Total + Qty
    Loop

Comment: Do While Not rs.EOF
        Qty = Nz(DLookup("[Quanity]", "tblTransActions", "[Tool_ID] = '" & Forms!frmMultiCkO!Tyonek_ID & "' AND [Patron_ID] = '" & Forms!frmMultiCkO!txtPatrons & "'"), 0)
        Total = Total + Qty
    Loop

Comment: The enter button is not doing the CR correctly.

Comment: Please update your question with the code.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.